# C# WPF GUI Design Question: Is it a bad idea to attach a background worker to a specific window

Tags: c#

I have an app which consist of three windows.

Main Window
Settings Window
Find Window

A dll needs to be initialized. THis is little time consuming, so i have it done via the backgroundworker. The backgroundworker is a private member of Main Window.

I need to check the status of the backgroundworker in the find window too. I can pass a reference of main window to find window and check the backgroundworker status.But is this way i have to do it. Or should i have the backgroundwroker in a seperate class(A singleton maybe) and check the status of the backgroundworker through that??

Not much experience in C# GUI programming.

Thanks

Comment: A singleton class called `MyDllLoader` which contains a method called `LoadDll` which starts a `BackgroundWorker` (in case the DLL is not already loaded) for loading the DLL, and which contains properties to query the status of the load would be a good solution IMHO.

Comment: More details on what you mean by 'C# GUI' would be useful. I am guessing that you mean WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) but Windows Forms would be at least one other possibility.

Comment: @Aviad - Your comment would probably have been more appropriate as an answer (see below).

Comment: @Scott-Its WPF. Edited the title

Answer (score 1):

If the entire purpose of the BackgroundWorker is to load a DLL without clogging up the UI message pump and to be able to be queried in odd spots, I would probably go with a singleton/static class.

You can then can design custom events that each window can attach to, to monitor the current state of the loading process.

That being said, it's dependant on how you've set up the relationship between the main window and the find window.

If the main window does all of the find window creation, then another option would be attach the background workers events to public methods on the find window.

I think both of these would would well, but i'm sure someone else with more knowledge will enlighten us both :)